# Skip tests if setup fails

Tags: gitlab-ci

In my GitLab CI pipeline, I perform some setup during my testing job.  Is there a way to skip the job if the setup fails?

The context is I'm testing on a set of Android phones being managed by an OpenSTF server.  So, my job looks like

```yaml
tests:
  stage: test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DEVICE:
        - phone1
        - phone2
        - ...
  script:
    - ./claim_device_and_adb_connect.sh $DEVICE
    - ./run_test.sh
```

In the case that a particular phone is offline or being used by someone else (so, `./claim_device_and_adb_connect.sh` fails), I'd like the test to be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can use the `allow_failure` directive:

```
tests:
  stage: test
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DEVICE:
        - phone1
        - phone2
        - ...
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - ./claim_device_and_adb_connect.sh $DEVICE
    - ./run_test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell script returns an error then I think by default gitlabs ci should stop the job.

You could take this a step further, and split the setup into a different stage that happens before the actual job and make the second stage depend on the first passing successfully.

Comment: Yes, it stops the job but it marks the job as having failed.  I'd like the job to be marked as skipped.

Comment: If you break them into multiple stages then I think it should skip the test job when the setup one fails. Is that not the functionality that you need?

Comment: It’s not, no.  I need the pipeline not to count as having failed.